# Should we add a [trackpad] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think we should add a tag for [trackpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackpad) - as a *tag synonym* of [touchpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touchpad).  "Trackpad" is in common usage, [partly due to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204895).  But we only have a tag for [touchpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touchpad).

I noticed there were [over 20 questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmouse%5D+trackpad) which include the word "trackpad", but are tagged as [mouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse) ("Use of this tag should be limited to questions pertaining to the peripheral input device known as a "mouse").  I suspect some people might try to use [trackpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackpad), notice the tag does not exist, and use [mouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse) instead.  This seems undesirable.

If you click on [touchpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touchpad), and then "[Synonyms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/touchpad/synonyms)", it says:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4

I can't vote there because I don't have *any* points in [touchpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) :-).

If there is a broad consensus, but we still don't have enough possible voters, it is also possible to ask an elected moderator to do this.

---

Wikipedia article: "[A touchpad or trackpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackpad) is a pointing device featuring a tactile sensor [...]"

Comment: Agreed, a simple and reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Looks like I have just enough points in [tag:touchpad], so I created the [tag:trackpad] tag and suggested it as a synonym. [Vote away!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/touchpad/synonyms)

Comment: There are like 8 users who can vote on that synonym, so we need 50% turnout at least. :/ Or a mod, and two of those 8 are mods.

Comment: Since there are so few users with the required reputation on the [tag:touchpad] tag, and since the response here looks primarily in favour for the synonym, I have created the synonym [tag:trackpad] for [tag:touchpad].